# Using ANTLR3 in a C++ program

Tags: c++, parsing, expression, antlr, antlr3

I'm currently working on an application that takes a string (a function of a single variable ' x') as input and outputs the derivative of that function. The latter half of the program is not the problem at the moment, the only thing I am having trouble with is "reading" a function from a string. I am using ANTLRv3 for C to try to achieve this goal, but I can't seem to get it to work. Currently I am missing the "antlr3.h" header file, which I can't seem to find anywhere. My second problem is invoking the generated parser, what would the C(++) code for that be (the ANTLR code is posted below)? How do I get it to work?

Thanks in advance,

Ties

```
grammar Expression;

options {
    language = C;
}

@header {
#ifndef PI
#define PI 3.1415926535897
#endif // PI

#ifndef E
#define E  2.7182818284590
#endif // E

#include "ExpressionTree.h"
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>}

parse returns [Functor* func]
    :   e=addExp EOF                {func = $e.func;}
    ;

addExp returns [Functor* func]
@init {std::vector<Functor*> addList;
       std::vector<bool> opList;}
    :   e1=multExp {addList.push_back($e1.func);} (o=('+'|'-') e2=multExp {opList.push_back($o.text == '+'); addList.push_back($e2.func);})*
{
if(addList.size() == 1) {
    func = addList[0];
} else {
    Functor* current = addList[0];
    for(int i = 0; i<opList.size(); i++) {
        if(opList[i]) {
            current = new Plus(current, addList[i+1]);
        } else {
            current = new Minus(current, addList[i+1]);
        }
    }
    func = current;
}};

multExp returns [Functor* func]
@init {
std::vector<Functor*> mulList;
std::vector<bool> opList;}
    :   e1=powExp {mulList.push_back($e1.func);} (o=('*'|'/') e2=powExp {opList.push_back($o.text == '*'); mulList.push_back($e2.func);})*
{
if(mulList.size() == 1) {
    func = addList[0];
} else {
    Functor* current = mulList[0];
    for(int i = 0; i<opList.size(); i++) {
        if(opList[i]) {
            current = new Times(current, mulList[i+1]);
        } else {
            current = new Divides(current, mulList[i+1]);
        }
    }
    func = current;
}};

powExp returns [Functor* func]
@init {
std::vector<Functor*> expList;
}
    :   e1=unarExp {expList.push_back($e1.func);} ('^' e2=unarExp {expList.push_back($e2.func);})?
{
if(expList.size() == 1) {
    func = expList[0];
} else {
    func = new Power(expList[0], expList[1]);
}};

unarExp returns [Functor* func]
    :   SQRT '(' e=addExp ')'           {func = new Sqrt($e.func);}
    |   SIN  '(' e=addExp ')'           {func = new Sin($e.func);}
    |   COS  '(' e=addExp ')'           {func = new Cos($e.func);}
    |   TAN  '(' e=addExp ')'           {func = new Tan($e.func);}
    |   EXP  '(' e=addExp ')'           {func = new Exp($e.func);}
    |   LOG  '(' e=addExp ')'           {func = new Log($e.func);}
    |   ABS  '(' e=addExp ')'           {func = new Abs($e.func);}
    |   MAX  '(' e1=addExp ',' e2=addExp ')'    {func = new Max($e1.func,$e2.func);}
    |   MIN  '(' e1=addExp ',' e2=addExp ')'    {func = new Min($e1.func,$e2.func);}
    |   e=atom                  {func = $e.func;}
    ;

atom returns [Functor* func]
    :   INT                 {func = new Constant(atoi($INT.text));}
    |   FLOAT               {func = new Constant(atof($FLOAT.text));}
    |   'pi'                {func = new Constant(PI);}
    |   'e'                 {func = new Constant(E);}
    |   'x'                 {func = new Variable();}
    |   '(' e=addExp ')'    {func = $e.func;}
    ;

SQRT:   'Sqrt';
SIN :   'Sin';
COS :   'Cos';
TAN :   'Tan';
EXP :   'Exp';
LOG :   'Log';
ABS :   'Abs';
MAX :   'Max';
MIN :   'Min';

INT     :   '0'..'9'+;
FLOAT   :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* EXPONENT?
    |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT
    ;
WS  :   ( ' ' | '\t') {$channel=HIDDEN;};

fragment
EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The antlr3.h file is the main header file of the ANTLR runtime. You can get this runtime from http://www.antlr3.org/download/C/ however, at the moment this page is not available.

For invocation: ANTLR generates a function for each of your parser rule that you can individually invoke. Usually you set up your parser and lexer and then call the parsers top level rule, in your case probably parse().

I have a parser for the MySQL language which I invoke so:

```
_input = antlr3StringStreamNew((pANTLR3_UINT8)_text, _input_encoding, _text_length, (pANTLR3_UINT8)"mysql-script");
_input->setUcaseLA(_input, ANTLR3_TRUE); // Make input case-insensitive. String literals must all be upper case in the grammar!

_lexer = MySQLLexerNew(_input);
_tokens = antlr3CommonTokenStreamSourceNew(ANTLR3_SIZE_HINT, TOKENSOURCE(_lexer));
_parser = MySQLParserNew(_tokens);

_ast = _parser->query(_parser);

ANTLR3_UINT32 error_count = _parser->pParser->rec->getNumberOfSyntaxErrors(_parser->pParser->rec);
if (error_count > 0)
  log_debug3("%i errors found\n", error_count);
```

Case sensitivity depends on your parser. Experiment a bit with that.